# How to change the string that I will not get error when string posted to server?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this ajax call:

```
    $.ajax( {           
      type: "POST",     
      url: "../someService",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json", 
      data: '{ prefixText:"'+ some"text +'", count:10 }', 
      success: function( data ) {   
       response(data.d);
      },
       error: function (error) {
         alert("error")
        }
    });
```

when the code is executed I get error because string that I sent to webService contains double-quotes.

How to change the string that I will not get error?

Comment: you got syntax error there - `some"text`

Comment: you can pass objects on your data.

Comment: @Eddie: Will jQuery handle it automatically if you're sending JSON rather than URI-encoded data? The docs don't seem to say, I've never got around to testing it...

Comment: @Eddie: Just tested it: No, it doesn't. You have to use `JSON.stringify`. jQuery still sends the object URI-encoded.

Comment: Ohh yeah, you are right. I just also tested it. We learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @Eddie: Disappointing, really, that's the sort of thing jQuery normally gets right. I suppose if they open the door they might get roped into supporting a bunch of formats, but...JSON seems worth it. :-) Tempted to open an issue for it and offer to do a PR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending JSON, so you need to be sure to send valid JSON. Your string is not valid JSON for at least a couple of reasons: You don't have your property keys in quotes, and you have a syntax error because of quoting.

**Don't hand-create JSON.** Instead, create the object and use a serializer to create the JSON for it:

```
$.ajax( {           
  type: "POST",     
  url: "../someService",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json", 
  data: JSON.stringify({ prefixText: "some" + text, count: 10 }),  // ***
  success: function( data ) {   
   response(data.d);
  },
   error: function (error) {
     alert("error")
    }
});
```

Comment: I want data to be sent dynamic (i.e. some times it has quotes some time not)

Comment: @Michael: The above is dynamic. You can change anything you want at runtime. The point is to create an object containing the data in the form you want to send, and the use `JSON.stringify` to turn that into valid JSON.

Comment: "some" is part of the text that can be changed

Comment: @Michael: So use a variable: `prefixText: theVariable + text`

Answer (score 0):

as you use JSON as your data type so you can use the object directly like

```js
$.ajax( {           
  type: "POST",     
  url: "../someService",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json", 
  data: { prefixText: "some" + text, count: 10 },  
  success: function( data ) {   
   response(data.d);
  },
   error: function (error) {
     alert("error")
    }
});
```

Comment: Will jQuery handle it automatically if you're sending JSON rather than URI-encoded data? The docs don't seem to say, I've never got around to testing it...

Comment: jQuery implicitly  using params serializing to send data I am always using this format to post data

Comment: Yes, it does that in the normal case, converting to URI-encoding. But **does it do that when you're sending JSON**? E.g., does it look at the `contentType` and serialize differently?

Comment: Just tested it: **No, it doesn't**. It still sends URI-encoded data. You have to use `JSON.stringify`. (Disappointing...)

Comment: If you check the network section in the browser developer tools you will find the data is sent but as querystring it depends on how you handle this in the back-end if you need it as string so it work automatically if you need a plain object you should parse it using JSON.stringify

Comment: Exactly: It's sent URI-encoded. But the `contentType` is for JSON. So the code above sends it incorrectly.